# How to include a concern in rakefile(task) Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, task, activesupport-concern

I have a concern I want to use in a task let's call it 'MyConcern', I include it like this

```
include MyConcern
```

There, I have an object called my_object, I get the following error when running the task.

> NameError: uninitialized constant MyConcern

Including the file like this instead of the above way:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../app/controllers/concerns/my_concern'
```

I get the following error, when running the task:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `my_object' for
>   main:Object

Btw, the object does have a value.

Am I missing any require? (in my task I am only including the file mentioned above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work by creating a service, this one includes the concern file, in that way I'm able to use the objects of the concern. I'm still not sure if that's the right way to do it, but it works.

**In services folder** *MyService.rb* in it the code.

```
class MyService
 include MyConcern

 def initialize; end
 def execute
  #stuff I have in my concern (for instance *my_object*)
 end
end
```

In the task I just use the service as usual.

```
MyService.new
```